# Concat two pivot table with different count of columns,in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have two pivot table with a distinct number of columns, and I need create one table with the value separated by commas in the cell but in the cell that not appear in the first table put 0.

For example

```
Table 1

       1      3    4
a     t1a1  t1a3 t1a4
b     t1b1  t1b3 t1b4

Table 2

       1    2    3    4
a     t2a1 t2a2 t2a3 t2a4
b     t2b1 t2b2 t2b3 t2b4
```

I want:

```
           1             2           3            4
a     (t1a1,t2a1)   (0,t2a2)  (t1a3,t2a3)   (t1a4,t2a4)
b     (t1b1,t2b1)   (0,t2b2)   (t1b3,t2b3)   (t1b4,t2b4)
```

The function

```
df = '(' + df1.astype(str) + ' , ' + df2.astype(str) + ')'
print (df)
```

Return

```
         1         2         3              4
a  (t1a1 , t2a1)  NaN  (t1a3 , t2a3)  (t1a4 , t2a4)
b  (t1b1 , t2b1)  NaN  (t1b3 , t2b3)  (t1b4 , t2b4)
```

I work in Python with pandas library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `df.reindex` and you're good to go!

```
'(' + df1.reindex(columns=df2.columns, fill_value='0') + ', ' + df2 + ')'

              1          2             3             4
a  (t1a1, t2a1)  (0, t2a2)  (t1a3, t2a3)  (t1a4, t2a4)
b  (t1b1, t2b1)  (0, t2b2)  (t1b3, t2b3)  (t1b4, t2b4)
```

Note that what you have are columns of *strings*, not columns of *tuples*. There's a difference.